# trying to start a standalone wiremockcsv application

Tags: wiremock

Has any one tried wiremock csv standalone application?

I did a mvn clean install for wiremockcsv and the build is successfull. I can see wiremockcsv-1.1.1-standalone.jar in my target folder. Then launched using the below command in my terminal

java -jar "##MyProjectPath##/WireMockCsv/target/wiremockcsv-1.1.1-standalone.jar" --port 8181 --root-dir ".\src\test\resources\factures\mock" --verbose

The application is launched successfully. But when I hit the below request in postman I get not found response. Can someone help me what I am missing here.
http://localhost:8181/rechercherClients

Response:

Error 404 
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /__files/rechercherClients. Reason:

```
    <pre>    Not Found</pre>
</p>
<hr />
<i>
    <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
</i>
```

and in my terminal i can see this
Matched response definition:
(no response definition configured)

When i hit http://localhost:8181/__admin
I get below response

```
{
"mappings": [],
"meta": {
"total": 0
}
}
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: you have to create mappings, the concept of wiremock is, you create mapping then start the server and server will behave seeing the mappings you defined, which you haven't defined I guess.

Answer (score 0):

With the demo project, the mappings are already done, it's ready to launch with  examples of all features.

In your case, the command line is not correct, if the current directory is not the project's base, it will not work, ##MyProjectPath## should be path of your project

Try this:

`java -jar "##MyProjectPath##\WireMockCsv\target\wiremockcsv-1.1.1-standalone.jar" --port 8181 --root-dir "**##MyProjectPath##**\src\test\resources\factures\mock" --verbose`

Or better and easier, directly with the provided Eclipse Launch Config ;-)